# Why do the variables need to be initialized in class in swift but they don't need to be initialized in struct?

Tags: swift

Im new to learn swift.I recently found that the variables or constants are needed to be initialized with an initial number or by the initializer.But in struct they don't need to be initialized?

Comment: Pretty sure they do. Do you have code examples showing otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

They do need.

From the Swift Language Guide:

> Classes and structures *must* set all of their stored properties to an
>   appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or
>   structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an
>   indeterminate state.
>
> You can set an initial value for a stored property within an
>   initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the
>   property’s definition.

Source: [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

Answer (score 1):

An example to @vadian 's answer:

```
struct S {
    init() {}
    let a: String
}
```

This will not compile:

```
Playground execution failed: Test.xcplaygroundpage:11:13: 
error: return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
init() {}
        ^
```

Comment: But for example I can define structure like    struct Person{  var name:String;  var age:Int}     without an initializer.In this case I have not declared any initial numbers to those two variables.But in class it can not compile with      class Person{ var name:String;    var age:Int  }.I need to declare it like   class Person{var name:String = "";   var age:Int = 0;}   or    class Person{var name:String;  var age:Int;    init(name:String, age :Int){ self.name = name;  self.age = age;}

Comment: @SamZhong Try to instantiate a struct with no initializer and whose variables have no default value: the complier complains again.